# Retrieve active childs in one to many association in grails

Tags: grails-2.0

I have below classes

```
class Audit {
    Status status = Status.ACTIVE
}

class Book{
    String name;
    Audit audit
    static embedded = ['audit']
    static belongsTo = [author:Author]
}

class Author{
    String name;
    Audit audit
    List books
    static embedded = ['audit']
    static hasMany = [books:Book]
}
```

I want to retrieve active books for the author. Can you suggest me the query for this?
I am trying to add method in Author like below

```
List<Book> getActiveBooks(){
}
```

or If there is any other way to retrieve my books.. as active books only.
Please help me out

Following are the tables with columns

> Book
>
> name, audit_status, author_id
>
> Author
>
> name, audit_status

Comment: I have updated with tables and columns for Book and Author. I thought it is simple question as i dont have much experience i am not getting it. I am surprising why i am not getting any answer. Please let me know if any thing need to know.

Answer (score 0):

Check out the [CriteriaBuilder](http://grails.org/doc/latest/guide/GORM.html#criteria).

You can use it to search on the status of the author (see "Querying Associations" section).

Use this together with projections (see "Querying with Projections") to get a list of books.

Answer (score 0):

One way of doing this is to add a namedQueries block in Author and then you can call

```
def activeBooks = Author.getActiveBooks().list()
```

Here is the Author class namedQueries

```
class Author {
    static namedQueries = {
        getActiveBooks {
            books {
               audit{
                eq 'status', Status.ACTIVE
               }
           }
        }
    }
}
```

I am assuming Status is a domain object too. If so, GORM will match the id of the status object.
Please double check the syntax.